# Meaning of "up to a scalar"

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

I have heard this used, within the context of results between the same up to a scalar, but I'm not sure of its meaning.

Can anyone provide an explanation and example in as simple terms as possible?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: It is always *much* better to give a specific example. "Up to a scalar" can mean a lot of different things, depending on context.

Comment: Perhaps an example could be: $(1,0)$ and $(4,0)$ are the same up to a scalar?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

To say that two things are the same up to a scalar multiple means that either of them is a scalar multiple of the other, and they are therefore considered equivalent.

An example is linear dependence among vectors.  Suppose $4\vec a + 2\vec b-9\vec c = \vec 0$, so that $(4,2,-9)$ is a linear dependence among the vectors $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$.  Then every nonzero scalar multiple of $(4,2,-9)$ is also a linear dependence among the vectors $\vec a,\vec b,\vec c$, and is essentially the same linear dependence. Thus one might say that up to a scalar multiple, $(4,2,-9)$ is the only linear dependence among these vectors.

For further examples see [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to).

Comment: Thank you for an explanation. One question: Say on month A there are two individuals: no 1. earns 100 dollars a month and spends 20 dollars  on food, while no.2 earns 12 dollars a month and spends 40 dollars on food. Then, assuming inflation increase by 2% from month A to B and the earnings and food prices increase by the same percentage between months A and B, for both individuals, could one state: "the share of earnings that each individual dedicates to food increased up to a scalar of 2%"

Comment: @StatsScared : If "share" means "percent", then it stayed the same. That is not the same usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: My mistake, I meant to say "amount" rather than "share". So: " the share of amount that each individual dedicates to food increased up to a scalar of 2%"

Comment: "the share of amount that each individual dedicates to food increased up to a scalar of 2%" still contains the word "share", so it doesn't necessarily clarify what that word is intended to mean.

Comment: Sorry, again. The phrase I'm inquiring on is: " the amount that each individual dedicates to food increased up to a scalar of 2%"